# Can't push/pull to/from brand new repository hooked up to Xcode

Tags: xcode, version-control, github

I'm really new at this, so thanks for your patience (and dealing with my frustration).

I've created a new Xcode project, put it under source control, and have successfully made changes/commits locally.

I've created a public repository at Github (https://github.com/nyuman/Beaner, and excuse the title it's an old inside joke. I'm making a bean counter).

And I've also successfully added that repository in Xcode. I used git as the username, my SSH link, etc.

The problem: when I push from Xcode I get a popup telling me "Working copy out of date. Trying pulling from the remote to get the latest changes, then push again."

So I then try and pull, upon which I get this popup: "Beaner/master" is not a valid remote branch to pull from. Please choose a different remote branch."

I've followed this guide 100%: http://www.raywenderlich.com/13771/how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-in-ios-6

I don't have any outstanding changes that need to be committed. Xcode tells me the remote repository is hooked up fine (green lights everywhere). This has happened practically every time and try and setup source control through Xcode and it's driving me crazy...

Comment: I had same issue, caused by creating readme.md file at github, delete the repo at github and recreate it with same name registered at xcode, but without creating readme.md file, then push from xcode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Were you successful or is the commit on github not from your xcode project?

Assuming you've already gone through the xcode steps of creating a new project and making some commits which you are now ready to push to github:

1. Create a new repo on github, say `nyuman/Beaner2`. Don't change anything else on github. Don't add a README.
2. Copy the ssh URL (assuming you just created the new repo): `git@github.com:nyuman/Beaner2.git`
3. Open a Terminal window and navigate to your project directory. In that window run:

   ```
   git remote add origin git@github.com:nyuman/Beaner2.git
   git push origin master:master
   ```

Unless there are additional local branches you wish to push, your repos should now be in sync.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. When I followed your suggestion, I got "The authenticity of host 'github.com (207.97.227.239)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48."

Comment: See ["Step 5"](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys), this is the expected RSA fingerprint for github, so accept it and it shouldn't prompt again.

Comment: I saw that I could accept it after my post. I accepted it an got a further error which I did not document. I think I've made a mess of things now. If I try to commit I get an error: "cannot do a partial commit during a merge". I'm not doing a merge, but I unsuccessfully tried one earlier. It failed and wanted me to do a commit. If I try doing a pull, I get an error that I need to commit or discard first. (discard is greyed out). If I try merge again, it wants me to commit or discard. Each one wants me to do an impossible thing first.

Comment: my previous comment happens when I try those actions in Xcode. If I try a git commit -a I get a message about a .swp file and hints at another application modifying the same file. This happens even when Xcode is not running.

Comment: I finally resolved my problem by creating a new repo with no readme and no .gitignore (those were making Xcode think something needed pulling). I did a git reset --merge from terminal. Then I was able to do a push.

Comment: The "Don't add a README" comment is about GitHub's option to add one to a new repo. I'd actually recommend that you have a README & .gitignore, but adding one when creating a repo makes pushing an existing repo harder.

Answer (score 2):

My workaround was to install GitHub for Mac.  Installed, entered my credentials for GitHub, selected the repo, pulled then pushed and all is well...Doesn't explain what is wrong with XCode 5.1...