# Remote Git repository unreachable in XCode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, git, version-control

I have created a remote Git repository for a new project. I have added to my remotes and XCode recognizes it. When creating the new project, I checked the box for Source Control > create git repository on: and selected "Add to New Server"

When I enter my login credentials, I get the following message:

The server https://... is unavailable or may not exist.  Check the server address, check your network connection, and then try again.

I have verified that my login is correct and the url is definitely valid. What might I be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked firewall configurations?

Comment: Yes, my firewall is off

Comment: Why is GIT using https protocol? Why not ssh or git protocol?

Comment: @Melr--not sure. I'm kinda new to using git on a remote server. Maybe I'm going about it wrong

Comment: So I've switched to SSH and am getting the following message:Try pulling from the remote to get the latest changes, then push again. This is a fresh repo with nothing in it. How can I get latest from an empty repo?

Comment: Did you create the repository on the github site?

Comment: Yes, I created a new repository on the github site, then tried to push my xcode project into it. I've tried https and ssh with the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to solve my issue using the following:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:pheepster/<repoName>.git
git push origin master:master
```

with the help of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14470400/2115842

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the two git commands in @Pheepster's answer, I suggest you check you are running the current version of GIT on both the development Mac and Server. Once I had the current version of GIT on both systems the two lines above solved my issue.